# How do I write the output of this loop to a script

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to write the output of this to a csv but am getting an error.

```
import csv

gas.enable_adc()
gas.set_adc_gain(4.096)

try:
    while True:
       readings = gas.read_all()
       logging.info(readings)
       time.sleep(1.0)

    print(readings)

    #These are the reading that I want to write to csv
    #Oxidising: 19768.76 Ohms
    #Reducing: 269925.93 Ohms
    #NH3: 368827.59 Ohms
    #ADC: 00.62 Volts

    with open('gas1.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
        csv.writer(csvfile)
        for x in readings:
            csvfile.writerow(x + ',' + '/n')

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

And this is the error I am getting:

> .Traceback (most recent call last):
>   .File "/home/pi/Documents/gas1.py", line 33, in 
>   .for x in readings:
>   .TypeError: 'Mics6814Reading' object is not iterabl.

Comment: What is `gas`? Where is it imported?

Comment: Sorry, gas is imported earlier in the script. It is from a environmental sensor.

Comment: The `readings` object is not iterable, look into the docs to find one that is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the source for [gas](https://github.com/pimoroni/enviroplus-python/blob/master/library/enviroplus/gas.py), you should be able to do

```py
readings = str(readings).split('\n')
```

This will first convert `readings` into a string, then split it into a list of lines, which can be iterated through in a for loop.

Comment: Thanks! This produces a row for each reading but each character occupies an individual cell. Any idea how to merge the cells?

Comment: If you remove the `.split()` what is the output?

Comment: Prints all readings in one column using a cell for each character. With .split() each reading occupies a separate row but the characters are in individual cells.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean, can you upload the output to pastebin?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/GTCyzNSn . Each character occupies a single cell

Comment: Also, this code i have overwrites the csv each time. I want it to write each reading without over writing.